# Which Android / Java Collection should I use for sorted keys value pairs, and to return elements after given point

Tags: java, android, collections

Lets say I have a list of keys that all contain an Object like this:

2, 4, 5, 9, 11

I need them to be ordered because I want to do something like:

```
function Object[] getObjectsAfter( int i ); 
// so 4 would result in an array of objects in the keys 5, 9 and 11
```

and

```
function Object[] getObjectsBefore( int i ); 
// so 4 would result in an array of objects in the keys 2
```

What collection is best to use in Android? I tried SparseArray and TreeMap, but I can't find a way to iterate from a certain point.

Comment: Have you tried a HashMap?

Comment: What about *LinkedList* ?

Comment: Are there duplicates? Do you need a map, or just a collection of these keys?

Comment: If you do not requires key-value pair structure then you can use ArrayList  and then for sorting purpose you case use **Collection** of java.util.Collections to sort your arraylist

Comment: No duplicates, HashMap and LinkedList are no good. Hashmap doesn't order anything. LinkedLists are not keyvalue pairs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you...

- ...need to have the elements ordered
- ...don't want duplicates
- ...want to be able to iterate from a specific point

you can use `TreeSet`.

**Demo:**

```
TreeSet<Integer> ints = new TreeSet<>(Arrays.asList(2,4,5,9,11));

System.out.println(ints.tailSet(4, false));  // [5, 9, 11]
System.out.println(ints.headSet(4, false));  // [2]
```

(If you want a `Map` you can use `TreeMap` with `tailMap` and `headMap`.)

Comment: The thing is, I also need direct acces. So that's why I ended up with a Map subclass.

Comment: Ah, goddamnit, I didn't read your answer right. So a map can have a head and a tail as well :). You just deserved yourself the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a SortedSet, it's a Set that further provides a total ordering on its elements. The elements are ordered using their natural ordering or by a Comparator typically provided at sorted set creation time (doc [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html)).